# How to get different IDs for each div in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4, and I have a div that I'm trying to repeat dynamically with a click event on it. The code is as shown below:

**map.component.html**

```
<div id="'EachClickDifferentID'" class="map" ></div>
```

**map.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, QueryList} from '@angular/core';

import * as ol from 'openlayers';

@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  host: {'[id]': 'id'},
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})



export class MapComponent implements OnInit {



  id: string  ;


  map: ol.Map = undefined;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({

      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([50.7753, 6.0839]),
        zoom: 3
      })
    });
  }

}
```

**Question:** How could i generate for each div a different id and bind it, so that my map will be rendered on every click event?
At the moment i only get one map by the first click event and nothing more.

To create dynamic components i am using the code above:

**app.component.widget.html**

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Widget Generator</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Fenstergenerator</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="grid.addDynamicCellComponent(selectedComponentType)">Add Widget</button>
                                </span>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedComponentType">
              <option *ngFor="let cellComponentType of componentTypes" [ngValue]="cellComponentType">{{cellComponentType.name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">DarstellungS</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <grid-component #grid></grid-component>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your `div` inside *ngFor ? If your div is in *ngFor you can use `index` of ngFor

Comment: No, i am not using *ngFor

Comment: than how do u 'repeat dynamically' ? pls post the html of `(click)` event and it's ts .

Comment: I posted the whole code, because i think it could be hard to understand otherwise. There are a few dependencies to create the components dynamicly.

Comment: But i thought there would be a possibility to # my id in the html code to a reference to dynamicly generated id in my map.component.ts?

Comment: is there only the posibility to create an index with *ngFor?

Comment: yes u can do something like this`*ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"` and in html `<div id="{{i}}">content</div>`